# I want to create a compiler with Coco/R and support IntelliSense

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, intellisense

I am a beginner in Compiler Engineering and I just want to know how to support IntelliSense.

Comment: you mean autocompletion because intellisense is microsoft's implementation of autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use reflection to generate documentation (XML is an option) that your IDE can pull from.